# react native how to display image in text

Tags: react-native

how can I display an image within a Text ?
The Problem is I can not see the Image

```
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Text style={{flex: 1, color: 'red', height: 50, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>This is a Text <ImageBackground style={{flex: 1, height: 100, width: 100}} source={require('../assets/profile.png')}/></Text>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Text** component should be *inside* the ImageBackground component, it's acting as a container, like a view, so maybe more like:

```
<View style={...}>
<ImageBackground style={...} source={require('../assets/profile.png')}/>
<Text style={...}>This is a Text</Text>
</ImageBackground>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't quite sure what you were looking for so: this would be an Image with Text on top of it.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, position: "absolute" }}>
              <ImageBackground
                style={{ flex: 1, height: 100, width: 100 }}
                source={require("../assets/profile.png")}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    color: "red",
                    height: 50,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  This is a Text
                </Text>
              </ImageBackground>
            </View>
```

And this is Text and Image inline:

```
   <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", position: "absolute" }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              color: "red",
              height: 50,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            This is
          </Text>
          <Image
            style={{ flex: 1, height: 100, width: 100 }}
            source={require("../assets/profile.png")}
          />
          <Text> a Text</Text>
        </View>
```